# How to get standard output from CreateProcessWithLogonW?

Tags: c#, winapi

I am using the code from http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.createprocesswithlogonw. How do I get the output from the standard output as a string? Like the stuff that shows up when you run it interactively in a command window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post solved it for me. Not the output part but that I got CreateProcessWithLogonW working.

http://blogs.msdn.com/alejacma/archive/2007/12/20/how-to-call-createprocesswithlogonw-createprocessasuser-in-net.aspx

Answer (score 3):

calling **CreateProcessWithLogonW** with redirected std input\output\error threads is same to executing code below using **System.Diagnostics.Process** class with user\domain\password fields specified and Redirect* fields set to true. In fact by looking into **StartWithCreateProcess** private method of the Process class using reflector you would find that **NativeMethods.CreateProcessWithLogonW** procedure gets executed there if conditions above are applied.

```
Process process1 = new Process();
process1.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\ping.exe";
process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "127.0.0.1";
// all 3 redirect* fields have to be set
process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process1.StartInfo.UserName = "admin";
process1.StartInfo.Domain = System.Environment.MachineName;
SecureString password = new SecureString();
foreach (char a in "password".ToCharArray())
    password.AppendChar(a);
process1.StartInfo.Password = password;
process1.Start();
string output = process1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(output);
process1.WaitForExit();
```

as for original question:

you would need to set pipe handles to stdOutput, stdError, stdInput fields of the StartupInfo. Smth like this:

```
StartupInfo startupInfo = new StartupInfo();
startupInfo.reserved = null;
startupInfo.flags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
startupInfo.showWindow = SW_SHOW;
...
SafeFileHandle inputHandle = null;
SafeFileHandle outputHandle = null;
SafeFileHandle errorHandle = null;

CreatePipe(out inputHandle, out startupInfo.stdInput, true);
CreatePipe(out outputHandle, out startupInfo.stdOutput, false);
CreatePipe(out errorHandle, out startupInfo.stdError, false);
```

below is CreatePipe implementation:

```
public static void CreatePipe(out SafeFileHandle parentHandle, out SafeFileHandle childHandle, bool parentInputs)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpPipeAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
    lpPipeAttributes.bInheritHandle = true;
    SafeFileHandle hWritePipe = null;
    try
    {
        if (parentInputs)
            CreatePipeWithSecurityAttributes(out childHandle, out hWritePipe, lpPipeAttributes, 0);
        else
            CreatePipeWithSecurityAttributes(out hWritePipe, out childHandle, lpPipeAttributes, 0);
        if (!DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), hWritePipe, GetCurrentProcess(), out parentHandle, 0, false, 2))
            throw new Exception();
    }
    finally
    {
        if ((hWritePipe != null) && !hWritePipe.IsInvalid)
        {
            hWritePipe.Close();
        }
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
{
    public int nLength;
    public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
    public bool bInheritHandle;
    public SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES()
    {
        nLength = 12;
        lpSecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool CreatePipe(out SafeFileHandle hReadPipe, out SafeFileHandle hWritePipe,
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpPipeAttributes, int nSize);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool DuplicateHandle(IntPtr hSourceProcessHandle, SafeHandle hSourceHandle,
    IntPtr hTargetProcess, out SafeFileHandle targetHandle, int dwDesiredAccess,
    bool bInheritHandle, int dwOptions);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

public static void CreatePipeWithSecurityAttributes(out SafeFileHandle hReadPipe, out SafeFileHandle hWritePipe,
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpPipeAttributes, int nSize)
{
    hReadPipe = null;
    if ((!CreatePipe(out hReadPipe, out hWritePipe, lpPipeAttributes, nSize) || hReadPipe.IsInvalid) || hWritePipe.IsInvalid)
        throw new Exception();
}
```

after you're done with creating pipes and CreateProcessWithLogonW is executed you can read std output from the pipe:

```
StreamWriter standardInput = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(inputHandle, FileAccess.Write, 0x1000, false), Console.InputEncoding, 0x1000);
standardInput.AutoFlush = true;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(outputHandle, FileAccess.Read, 0x1000, false), Console.OutputEncoding, true, 0x1000);
StreamReader error = new StreamReader(new FileStream(errorHandle, FileAccess.Read, 0x1000, false), Console.OutputEncoding, true, 0x1000);

while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
   string line = reader.ReadLine();
   if (line.Length>0) Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

code above is basically what is done in the StartWithCreateProcess method of the Process class

hope this helps, regards

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the following overload of [Process.Start Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxf2saat.aspx) ?

Comment: It didn't work for me. I get "The application failed to initialize properly" See related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972649/help-with-using-createprocesswithlogonw-in-c/1972860#1972860