# CreateProcessWithLogonW get standard output

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I found the below comment on [Microsoft's documentation site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Also, CreateProcessWithLogonW rejects STD handles (0/1/2) i.e. what GetStdHandle() returns by default, when using STARTF_USESTDHANDLES. It returns error 6, invalid handles, because 0/1/2 are not "real" handles. The only way we found to redirect the console input/output was to create custom handles (pipes) and use those instead (e.g. even just as dummy handles that you don't use). This is missing functionality from CreateProcessWithLogonW, because CreateProcess (and maybe CreateProcessAsUser, I didn't verify that) accepts STD handles.

This points to creating custom pipes.

I found [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973376/how-to-get-standard-output-from-createprocesswithlogonw) which points to using things such as `"SafeFileHandle"`. This is apparently C++/CLI which I am not familiar with how to use. I am using Visual C++ and therefore "native" C++?

I am looking for a simple solution of how to fix this issue. I am a newbie in C++ and the CLI thing confused me because I simply don't know how to use it, or make Visual C++ compatible with it.

Given my normal C++ and my question, HOW EXACTLY would I create the custom pipe which will allow me to get the standard output?

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

void DisplayError(LPWSTR pszAPI)
{
    LPVOID lpvMessageBuffer;

    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
        NULL, GetLastError(), 
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), 
        (LPWSTR)&lpvMessageBuffer, 0, NULL);

    //
    //... now display this string
    //
    wprintf(L"ERROR: API        = %s.\n", pszAPI);
    wprintf(L"       error code = %d.\n", GetLastError());
    wprintf(L"       message    = %s.\n", (LPWSTR)lpvMessageBuffer);

    //
    // Free the buffer allocated by the system
    //
    LocalFree(lpvMessageBuffer);

    ExitProcess(GetLastError());
}

void _tmain(int argc, WCHAR *argv[])
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

    HANDLE pipe1 = CreateNamedPipe(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\pipe1", PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
               PIPE_WAIT, 1024, 1024, 1024, 60, NULL);
    HANDLE pipe2 = CreateNamedPipe(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\pipe2", PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
               PIPE_WAIT, 1024, 1024, 1024, 60, NULL);
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.hStdOutput = pipe1;
    si.hStdError =  pipe2;

    DWORD     dwSize;
    HANDLE    hToken;
    LPVOID    lpvEnv;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};
    WCHAR               szUserProfile[256] = L"";

    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

    if (argc != 4)
    {
        wprintf(L"Usage: %s [user@domain] [password] [cmd]", argv[0]);
        wprintf(L"\n\n");
        return;
    }

    //
    // TO DO: change NULL to '.' to use local account database
    //
    if (!LogonUser(argv[1], NULL, argv[2], LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, 
            LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hToken))
        DisplayError(L"LogonUser");

    if (!CreateEnvironmentBlock(&lpvEnv, hToken, TRUE))
        DisplayError(L"CreateEnvironmentBlock");

    dwSize = sizeof(szUserProfile)/sizeof(WCHAR);

    if (!GetUserProfileDirectory(hToken, szUserProfile, &dwSize))
        DisplayError(L"GetUserProfileDirectory");

    //
    // TO DO: change NULL to '.' to use local account database
    //
    if (!CreateProcessWithLogonW(argv[1], NULL, argv[2], 
            LOGON_WITH_PROFILE, NULL, argv[3], 
            CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, lpvEnv, szUserProfile, 
            &si, &pi))
        DisplayError(L"CreateProcessWithLogonW");

    if (!DestroyEnvironmentBlock(lpvEnv))
        DisplayError(L"DestroyEnvironmentBlock");

    CloseHandle(hToken);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

I tried this and I am getting no output on the console window. As I said, I checked the answer on StackOverflow and this whole C++/CLI thing confuses me. If someone knows a simple solution to redirecting the output using a custom pipe using Visual C++, let me know.

And if I did anything wrong above, let me know as well.

EDIT:

After following the suggestions given by Remy's answer. I came up with the following code, which yields an error code 3: The system cannot find the path specified.

```
#include "stdafx.h"


HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;

HANDLE g_hInputFile = NULL;


int BUFSIZE = 1064;
void CreateChildProcess(void); 
void WriteToPipe(void); 
void ReadFromPipe(void); 
void ErrorExit(PTSTR); 

void DisplayError(LPWSTR pszAPI)
{
    LPVOID lpvMessageBuffer;

    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
        NULL, GetLastError(), 
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), 
        (LPWSTR)&lpvMessageBuffer, 0, NULL);

    //
    //... now display this string
    //
    wprintf(L"ERROR: API        = %s.\n", pszAPI);
    wprintf(L"       error code = %d.\n", GetLastError());
    wprintf(L"       message    = %s.\n", (LPWSTR)lpvMessageBuffer);

    //
    // Free the buffer allocated by the system
    //
    LocalFree(lpvMessageBuffer);

    ExitProcess(GetLastError());
}





void _tmain(int argc, WCHAR *argv[])
{

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr; 
   saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
   saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
   saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 

   if ( ! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0) ) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("StdoutRd CreatePipe")); 

   if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )
      ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdout SetHandleInformation")); 

    if (! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &saAttr, 0)) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin CreatePipe")); 

    if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )
      ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin SetHandleInformation")); 

    /////////////////////////////Start CreateChildProcess////////



    STARTUPINFO si;
    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    si.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    si.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;

    DWORD     dwSize;
    HANDLE    hToken;
    LPVOID    lpvEnv;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};
    WCHAR               szUserProfile[256] = L"";

    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

    if (argc != 4)
    {
        wprintf(L"Usage: %s [user@domain] [password] [cmd]", argv[0]);
        wprintf(L"\n\n");
        return;
    }

    //
    // TO DO: change NULL to '.' to use local account database
    //
    if (!LogonUser(argv[1], NULL, argv[2], LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, 
            LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hToken))
        DisplayError(L"LogonUser");

    if (!CreateEnvironmentBlock(&lpvEnv, hToken, TRUE))
        DisplayError(L"CreateEnvironmentBlock");

    dwSize = sizeof(szUserProfile)/sizeof(WCHAR);

    if (!GetUserProfileDirectory(hToken, szUserProfile, &dwSize))
        DisplayError(L"GetUserProfileDirectory");

    //
    // TO DO: change NULL to '.' to use local account database
    //
    if (!CreateProcessWithLogonW(argv[1], NULL, argv[2], 
            LOGON_WITH_PROFILE, NULL, argv[3], 
            CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, lpvEnv, szUserProfile, 
            &si, &pi))
        DisplayError(L"CreateProcessWithLogonW");

    if (!DestroyEnvironmentBlock(lpvEnv))
        DisplayError(L"DestroyEnvironmentBlock");

    CloseHandle(hToken);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);



    /////////////////////////////End CreateChildProcess///////////

     if (argc == 1) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("Please specify an input file.\n")); 

   g_hInputFile = CreateFile(
       argv[3], 
       GENERIC_READ, 
       0, 
       NULL, 
       OPEN_EXISTING, 
       FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY, 
       NULL); 

   if ( g_hInputFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("CreateFile")); 

     WriteToPipe(); 
   printf( "\n->Contents of %s written to child STDIN pipe.\n", argv[1]);


      printf( "\n->Contents of child process STDOUT:\n\n", argv[1]);
   ReadFromPipe(); 

}

void WriteToPipe(void) 

// Read from a file and write its contents to the pipe for the child's STDIN.
// Stop when there is no more data. 
{ 
   DWORD dwRead, dwWritten; 
   CHAR chBuf[4096];
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

   for (;;) 
   { 
      bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hInputFile, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
      if ( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 ) break; 

      bSuccess = WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
      if ( ! bSuccess ) break; 
   } 

// Close the pipe handle so the child process stops reading. 

   if ( ! CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr) ) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("StdInWr CloseHandle")); 
} 

void ReadFromPipe(void) 

// Read output from the child process's pipe for STDOUT
// and write to the parent process's pipe for STDOUT. 
// Stop when there is no more data. 
{ 
   DWORD dwRead, dwWritten; 
   CHAR chBuf[4096]; 
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
   HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

   for (;;) 
   { 
      bSuccess = ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
      if( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 ) break; 

      bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf, 
                           dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
      if (! bSuccess ) break; 
   } 
} 

void ErrorExit(PTSTR lpszFunction) 

// Format a readable error message, display a message box, 
// and exit from the application.
{ 
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf)+lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction)+40)*sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, 
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"), 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf); 
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use anonymous pipes via `CreatePipe()`, not named pipes via `CreateNamedPipe()`.  See MSDN for an example:

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx)

Comment: I am getting a "CreateFile failed with error code 2: system cannot find the file specified" when I run it using the example you gave me. It seems to be on the right track. Do you have any idea why it would give me such an error? Or how to fix it?

Comment: My CreateFile line is this:  g_hInputFile = CreateFile(
       argv[1], 
       GENERIC_READ, 
       0, 
       NULL, 
       OPEN_EXISTING, 
       FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY, 
       NULL);

Comment: `argv[1]` is your app's `user@domain` command-line parameter.  Use `argv[3]` instead.

Comment: I did this and now I am getting an error code 3: cannot find specified route (or something like that). Do you know why this is?

Comment: Do you think it may have something to do with the fact that argv[3] is in quotes and has parameters within it?

Comment: Error code 3 is `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`. If `argv[3]` contains a full command line, not just an executable filename, then you may have to pre-parse and re-format it into something that `CreateProcessWithLogonW()` will accepts. What does the value of `argv[3]` actually look like?

Comment: It is something like this:  "reg query \\MY_COMPUTER\HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet"

Comment: I think CreateProcessWithLogonW() does accept this kind of command. I was using "reg add" before, with a similar format... and it was correctly modifying the registry.. it is only when trying to gather the output that I get these messages. Maybe the issue is in another part of the code?

Comment: Why are you using an external process to access the Registry? You should instead impersonate the user account using `LogonUser()` and `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()`, and then use Registry API functions like `RegConnectRegistry()`, `RegOpenKeyEx()`, `RegEnumKeyEx()`, `RegQueryValueEx()`, etc instead.

Comment: I am extremely unfamiliar not only with API functions, but with C++ programming in general. I wanted the quickest way to execute these registry operations, and the fastest way for me was, using a remote process. I would experiment with what you mention but wouldn't that take me too long? The stuff I am doing was pretty much due yesterday lol :)

Comment: what do you suggest I do given the fact that I have time as a priority. Should I try out the functions you mention? Given the fact I am still a newbie in terms of using API and C++?

Comment: They are not difficult API functions to use.  I do suggest you use them instead of a remote process.

Comment: OK Remy. Thank you for your suggestions. I will follow them. :) Also, regarding the question itself, do you know why it might pop out this error. I do not think reg query would be the only command that produces this error?

Comment: You are relying on a relative path when calling reg.exe. Always use a full path instead, eg: "C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe query \\MY_COMPUTER\HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet".  You can use `GetSystemDirectory()` to dynamically locate the actual location of the System32 folder at runtime.

Comment: I get the same error even with absolute paths. I have edited my orignal question to include the code I now have, in case you are able to notice something else. However, I will try your suggestions of using the reg APIs you mentioned. I will also accept your answer and thanks for your time!!! If you do notice the root of this error or can reproduce it and know its cause, let me know. I am curious to see this error fixed. However, as I said I will move on to trying what you suggested for reg query.

Comment: UPDATE: I fixed the issue. It turns out the "CreateFile" function that was giving me the error, corresponded to the INPUT FILE. However, my purpose was only to get the OUTPUT. Therefore, such an input file was unnecessary for my purposes, so I just deleted the part where it creates an input file. And the program worked. Thanks to Remy for the correct example that led to my solution. Cheers.