# Run application as another domain user

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-10, impersonation

I have a program that launches a bunch of other programs automatically.

One of those programs is DSAC.EXE, Active Directory Administrative Center.

For it to be used properly with correct rights, it has to be launch from another user. A domain admin user. The exact copy of their daytime profile, but with enhanced privileges.

I have this code that works perfectly with Windows 7. But doesn't with Windows 10 :

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.AS_P_CAD == true)
            {
                if (File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\system32\dsac.exe") | File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\sysnative\dsac.exe"))
                {
                    Process[] CAD_Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("dsac.exe");
                    if (CAD_Process.Length == 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Process proc = new Process();
                            System.Security.SecureString ssPwd = new System.Security.SecureString();
                            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "dsac.exe";
                            //proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "args...";
                            proc.StartInfo.Domain = "somedomain.local";
                            proc.StartInfo.UserName = Crypto.Decrypt(Properties.Settings.Default.ADM_Login);
                            string password = Crypto.Decrypt(Properties.Settings.Default.ADM_);
                            for (int x = 0; x < password.Length; x++)
                            {
                                ssPwd.AppendChar(password[x]);
                            }
                            password = "";
                            proc.StartInfo.Password = ssPwd;
                            proc.Start();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            dMessageBox.Show("Information", $"Active Directory Administrative Center could not be launched.\n\nError :\n{ex.Message}", MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dMessageBox.Show("Already running", "Active Directory Administrative Center is already running", MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dMessageBox.Show("Canceled", "Active Directory Administrative Center is not installed.\nThere is nothing to launch !", MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
```

I've tried multiple other solutions, one with with Impersonator, but nothing seems to work.

Message is "canceled by user".

I've come accross a solution with CreateProcessWithLogonW, but i have no idea how to use it.

Any thoughts?

---

EDIT :

I've tried with Impersonate : FAILED

With CreateProcessWithLogonW : FAILED (still returns "requires elevation")

Can it be done by disabling UAC ? And re-enabling it right away ?

Or through a batch or a Console Line ?

Please help.

---

EDIT#2 :

Works with a .bat file launched through CreateProcessWithLogonW.

This is just ridiculous. I hate Win10. :x

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972649/help-with-using-createprocesswithlogonw-in-c-sharp

Comment: i need a more ... let's say ... beginner-friendly documentation. :)

Comment: When it comes to `pinvoke` it's very rare you get anything thats 'Beginner Friendly'

Comment: I mean, i want to understand at least. Copy/pasting code is not what i want to do here.

Comment: Using CreateProcessWithLogonW still returns error 740 (which is "Requires an elevation"). Is there any other solution ? Disabling UAC just the time i need to launch this programm and re-enabling it right away. Running the program through a Batch file or a command line ? I don't know, anyone ? :x